# trouble getting function to run, python

Tags: python, function

For my python class I was instructed to create a function that will read a file and report the number of lines, words, and characters. I can get the code to work, but once I try to convert it to a function, it doesn't work. what's wrong? I also need to return the values in a tuple. I keep getting this error:UnboundLocalError: local variable 'line_cnt' referenced before assignment

```
def file_elem(filenm):
    f = open(filenm,'r')
    wrd_cnt = 0
    char_cnt = 0
    line_len = 0
    while f is open:
        line_cnt = len(f.readlines( ))
        for line in f:
            f_lines = line.split()
            wrd_cnt += len(f_lines)
            no_spaces = ''.join(line.split())
            char_cnt += len(no_spaces)
    return print(line_cnt, wrd_cnt, char_cnt)

import os
x = os.path.join("C:", "\\temp", "practice4.txt")
file_elem(x)
```

Comment: You are returning the result of the function `print`. You probably want to drop the `print` from the return line, and print the result outside the function.

Comment: By the way, does this code really works? `while f is open` looks very suspicious to me... (you are checking whether `f` and the global function `open` are the same object).

Comment: `while f is open` is now my new favourite bit of English which is syntactically valid Python but doesn't do at all what a beginner would expect..

Comment: I second! `while f is open` should be a new PEP recommendation! Seems more natural than `with open("file") as f`!

Comment: I see, when I change the code to with open("file") as f, it does return the first value correctly, but gives 0 for the last two values

Comment: kflaw, there are other issues - for example, after you call `f.readlines()`, you cannot continue reading lines from `f` (in a loop), because the file cursor is at the end of the file.

Comment: you don't need to add the `\\ ` before `temp`, `join` does it. Try running the code by removing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `while f is open` to `with open(filenm,'r') as f` and remove `f = open(filenm,'r')`. And move the `return (line_cnt, wrd_cnt, char_cnt)` inside the with block!

Also, you don't need `line_cnt = len(f.readlines( ))`. You should use a counter and increment it. Otherwise the file would be read before your `for line in f`!

Comment: def file_elem(filenm):
        f = open(filenm,'r')
        line_cnt = 0
        wrd_cnt = 0
        char_cnt = 0
        line_cnt = len(f.readlines( ))
        with open(filenm) as f:
            for line in f:
                f_lines = line.split()
                wrd_cnt += len(f_lines)
                no_spaces = ''.join(line.split())
                char_cnt += len(no_spaces)
            return (line_cnt, wrd_cnt, char_cnt)

import os
x = os.path.join("C:", "\\temp", "practice4.txt")
print (file_elem(x))

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
return print(line_cnt, wrd_cnt, char_cnt)
```

to

```
return (line_cnt, wrd_cnt, char_cnt)
```

and this

```
file_elem(x)
```

to:

```
print file_elem(x)
```

and it should work the same as before.
Your function returns the values. Your main program prints them.

Comment: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'line_cnt' referenced before assignment

Comment: As Omri Barel said, your while loop won't really work as you expect it to, so `line_cnt` is not going to be defined, and that's why you get the error.

Comment: Guess the print was withing the while loop initially!